# Property of exterior derivative of alternating forms

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

These are the definitions

Let $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\omega:U\to\Lambda^kT^*\mathbb{R}^n$ a smooth k-form such that in local coordinates is written as

$\omega(\underline{x})=\Sigma_{_I^{\to}}\omega_{_I^{\to}}(\underline x)dx_{_I^{\to}}$,     with $\omega_{_I^{\to}}:U\to\mathbb{R}$ smooth;
we define de exterior derivative of $\omega$ by

$d\omega_{\underline x}(v_1,...,v_{k+1})=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i-1}\omega_{*,\underline x}(v_i)(v_1,...,\hat v_i,...,v_{k+1})$

$\hspace{3.5cm}=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac{\partial\omega_{_I^{\to}}}{\partial v_i}\vert_{\underline x}  dx_{_I^{\to}}(v_1,...,\hat v_i,...,v_{k+1}).$

I have to prove this property of the differential:

If $\omega=fdx_{_I^{\to}}\Rightarrow d\omega=df\wedge dx_{_I^{\to}}$
I do not know how to prove that... ($f$ is a 0-form)

I only know that

$d\omega_{\underline x}(v_1,...,v_k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i-1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_i}dx_{_I^{\to}}(v_1,...,\hat v_i,...,v_{k+1})$
$=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{i-1}d_{\underline x}f(v_i)dx_{_I^{\to}}(v_1,...,\hat v_i,...,v_{k+1})$ and now?
[image: the above definition]

Comment: The definition you've written down makes no sense.

Comment: What you put from the book makes sense, of course. You're differentiating $\omega$ as a map from $U$ to the vector space of multilinear maps. But neither $\omega_*$ nor $\partial\omega_I/\partial v_i$ makes sense.

Comment: Please let me understand: $\omega:U\to\Lambda^kT^*\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map between two differential manifolds, so i could calculate its tangent map in a point $\underline x$  $\omega_{*,\underline x}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\Lambda^k\mathbb{R}^n$. If $\omega=fdx_{I^{\to}}$ it maps $e_j\mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\vert_{\underline x}dx_{I^{\to}}.$ We could see this map like the usual differential using to the vectorial isomorphism $\Lambda^k\mathbb{R}^n\cong\mathbb{R}^{\binom{n}{k}},$ why it make no sense? Otherwise, with the notation of the book, how could i prove the above result?